# Include a php file into another in a wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

im tring to include a php file into another using php **include** function, i'm working on a **wordpress** based website, i'm structuring an email form, with php mailer.
For the file that are in my main root folder i can use the function **get_template_part()** but if he file is in a subfolder this function doesn't work, so im'tring to use the **include** function but i have a problem with the path, i don't know why the include function doesn't accept the bloginfo('template_url') function, can anyone help me? this is my code:

```html
<?php

$template_url = bloginfo('template_url');
$url_mailer = $template_url . '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

include '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//require $url_mailer;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtps.aruba.it'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'postmaster@laveraitalia.us'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'r2fmee2k'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name . $surname;
$mail->addAddress($reciver); // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name . $surname);
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz'); // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if (!$mail->send()) {
 $logmessage = "<span class=\"bg-danger\">The message hasn't been sent, try again</span>";
} else {
 $logmessage = "<span class=\"bg-success\">The message has been sent</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Try providing the the full path , i.e.: `include '/home/site/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'`

Comment: Does `bloginfo('template_directory')` (rather than ``bloginfo('template_url')``) work?

Comment: you need the full path of the server /var/www/html/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php or something like that. include("/var/www/html/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

Comment: include 'http://localhost/laveraitalia/wp-content/themes/LaVeraItalia/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  i tried using the path directly but this message appear Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\laveraitalia\wp-content\themes\LaVeraItalia\mail.php on line 6

Comment: require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laveraitalia\wp-content\themes\LaVeraItalia/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; this is working, thanks